# How to fetch Google App Engine logs in minute chunks via appcfg.py?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

My latest project expects 100.000 unique visitors a day and I started to use Google App Engine to be able to scale the infrastructure according to the load.

I would like to fetch log lines with `appcfg.py request_logs` every minute to get the latest data and add them to my monitoring dashboard utilizing LogStash/ElasticSearch/Kibana.

Is there a way to tell `appcfg.py request_logs` to load the log lines from an explicit time range like a minute from 2014-10-10T10:00:00 to 2014-10-10T10:01:00 ?

I am a bit afraid that I have too many log lines and I am not able to retrieve all of them because of limit to the number of lines the `appcfg.py request_logs` can retrieve, that I may incurring too much cost if I retrieve all log lines every minute, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify by days:

> -n NUM_DAYS, --num_days=NUM_DAYS
>                         Number of days worth of log data to get. The cut-off
>                         point is midnight US/Pacific. Use 0 to get all
>                         available logs. Default is 1, unless --append is also
>                         given; then the default is 0.

I haven't tried this myself but if you can create a local script to process a website you use the [Logs API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions) to generate a webpage that is read from your script. Make sure to set the login as admin only to prevent others from reading it.